# Не могу получить ТекстКонтент из нужных квадратов

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: Программа которую имеем]

Так вот, есть программа в которой 18 квадратов, квадраты разворачиваются, НО у всех квадратов своя задержка и поворот происходит не по порядку.

```
var n = 0; //переменная для счетчика 
function showMessage() { //функция для логирования состояния карт

    textarea.value += "\nКонец процесса " + (card[n].textContent); //добавляем эту строку после того как карта будет перевернута 
    n = ++n %  card.length; //как только остаток от деления счетчика увеличенного на еденицу поделенного на длинну массива станет равен 1
    if(!n) {button.value = "пуск"; textarea.value += "\nКонец всех процессов";} //поменяем названием кнопки на "пуск"
}

element.addEventListener("transitionend", showMessage, false) //слушатель события который висит на каждом элементе контейнера с картами, при окончании движения он вызывает функцию showmessage
```

Есть вот такой вот код, но этот код не отображает нужных цифр, он отображает вывод в текст ареа просто по цифр по порядку, а нам надо что бы он отображал конец процесса именно того кубика который закончил поворот